# Al filtrar directorios con el comando find aparecen archivos extraños dentro de /proc

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unix, awk, búsquedas

Tengo lo siguiente en un shell script:

```
  for i in $(find /proc -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep "[0-9]"); do
    printf "%s\t" $(cat $i/status | grep "Uid" | awk '{print $2}')
    printf "%s\t" $(cat $i/status | grep "^Pid:" | awk '{print $2}')
    printf "%s\t" $(cat $i/status | grep "PPid" | awk '{print $2}')
    printf "%s\t" $(cat $i/status | grep "State" | awk '{print $2}')
    printf "%.35s\t\n" $(cat $i/cmdline | awk '{print $1}')
  done
```

Cumple su función, que es listar algo de información de los procesos en ejecución. El problema es que también procesa algunos archivos que no puedo encontrar:

> cat: /proc/21007/status: No existe el archivo o el directorio

¿Qué son estas carpetas dentro de /proc/? Descriptores de procesos no pueden ser dado que no presentan un archivo status como debería ser...

Comment: ¿De dónde has sacado este shell script? Es una auténtica barbaridad lo que hace de ir escribiendo `cat fichero | grep | awk` cada vez, cuando con `awk` podrías coger todo el resultado de una vez y escribirlo de una forma más limpia. Por otra parte, iría bien un [mcve] para poder replicar el error. Para empezar, ¿en qué distribución y versión lo ejecutas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proc` es un filesystem especial utilizado como interfaz con las estructuras de datos del kernel. Normalmente se monta en `/proc/`, como es tu caso.

Puedes ver una descripción muy detallada en [`man proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). De allí extraigo mi interpretación de sus explicaciones.

Simplificando, cada proceso que tienes abierto genera un árbol de directorios con su número. De este modo, el proceso principal del sistema, cuyo PID es 1, genera `/proc/1`, bajo cuya raíz puedes encontrar una serie de subdirectorios.

En tu caso, el script está buscando tooooodos los directorios correspondientes a los PID en ejecución. Una vez los tiene, para cada uno muestra su información a través de la interfaz `/proc/<PID>/status`, que da bastande de la información de `/proc/<PID>/stat` y `/proc/<PID>/statm` de una forma más leíble.

Pero tu problema no es este, sino el error:

> ```
> cat: /proc/21007/status: No existe el archivo o el directorio
> ```

Aquí parece que ha pasado lo siguiente: `find` ha encontrado una serie de PID y los ha pasado al `for`. A continuación, y una vez terminado de devolver el listado, el `for` ha empezado a iterar sobre ellos. Cuando ha llegado al PID 21007, ha resultado que el proceso ya había terminado, luego la estructura de directorios `/proc/21007/` ya no existe. Y allí te lo dice.

Desconozco cuál es la finalidad de tu script, pero a buen seguro podrías ir recorriendo directamente el directorio `/proc/` sin necesidad de poner un `find` por el medio. Así te evitarías este problema.

---

Este es el ejemplo que sale en `man proc(5)` de salida de `cat /proc/<PID>/status`:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/status
  Name:   bash
  Umask:  0022
  State:  S (sleeping)
  Tgid:   17248
  Ngid:   0
  Pid:    17248
  PPid:   17200
  TracerPid:      0
  Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
  Gid:    100     100     100     100
  FDSize: 256
  Groups: 16 33 100
  NStgid: 17248
  NSpid:  17248
  NSpgid: 17248
  NSsid:  17200
  VmPeak:     131168 kB
  VmSize:     131168 kB
  VmLck:           0 kB
  VmPin:           0 kB
  VmHWM:       13484 kB
  VmRSS:       13484 kB
  RssAnon:     10264 kB
  RssFile:      3220 kB
  RssShmem:        0 kB
  VmData:      10332 kB
  VmStk:         136 kB
  VmExe:         992 kB
  VmLib:        2104 kB
  VmPTE:          76 kB
  VmPMD:          12 kB
  VmSwap:          0 kB
  HugetlbPages:          0 kB        # 4.4
  Threads:        1
  SigQ:   0/3067
  SigPnd: 0000000000000000
  ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
  SigBlk: 0000000000010000
  SigIgn: 0000000000384004
  SigCgt: 000000004b813efb
  CapInh: 0000000000000000
  CapPrm: 0000000000000000
  CapEff: 0000000000000000
  CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
  CapAmb:   0000000000000000
  NoNewPrivs:     0
  Seccomp:        0
  Cpus_allowed:   00000001
  Cpus_allowed_list:      0
  Mems_allowed:   1
  Mems_allowed_list:      0
  voluntary_ctxt_switches:        150
  nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     545
```